# QTime Buffer Overflow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am writing a program that asks the user for a large number of seconds and waits that many seconds. The issue is that as soon as waitSecs is larger 9999 seconds, launchTime seems to become a random number. I've outputted waitSecs using qDebug and it is the correct number (even when the number is larger than 9999). Any help?

```
QTime launchTime = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(waitSecs);
```

Here is the code + output:

[image]

Comment: In the question you say "9999 seconds", but in the program output is "99999".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Qt documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html#addSecs:

```
QTime QTime::addSecs ( int s ) const
```

Returns a QTime object containing a time s seconds later than the time of this object (or earlier if s is negative).

**Note that the time will wrap if it passes midnight.**

Consider using QDateTime instead...

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! I didn't understand what they meant by wrap so I thought it was irrelevant.